# Working with typedef enums in structs and avoiding type mixing warnings

Tags: c, struct, enums, typedef, iar

I am working with C99. My compiler is IAR Embedded workbench but I assume this question will be valid for some other compilers too.

I have a typedef enum with a few items in it and I added an element to a struct of that new type

```
typedef enum
{
    foo1,
    foo2
} foo_t;

typedef struct
{
    foo_t my_foo;
    ...
} bar_t;
```

Now I want to create an instance of bar_t and initialize all of its memory to 0.

```
bar_t bar = { 0u };
```

This generates a warning that I mixing an enumerated with another type. The IAR specific warning number is Pe188. It compiles and works just fine since an enum is an unsigned int at the end of the day. But I'd like to avoid a thousand naggy warnings. What's a clean way to initialize struct types that have enumerated types in them to 0?

for the sake of argument lets assume bar_t has a lot of members - I want to just set them all to 0. I'd rather not type out something like this:

```
bar_t bar = { foo1, 0u, some_symbol,... , 0u};
```

EDIT: Extra note: I am complying with MISRA. So if a workaround is going to violate MISRA it just moves the problem for me. I'll get nagged by the MISRA checker instead.

Comment: Provide an enum with the "default" value?

Comment: Well, in this case the "default" value would be foo1 because unless I specify otherwise it will be 0. But even if I said foo1 = 0, in the enum I still see this warning.

Comment: You would have to do `bar_t bar = { foo1 };` do you still see a warning in this case? (Provided you defined foo1 as 0)

Comment: I am going to edit my OP - I also have to comply with MISRA rules. Doing this gets rid of the compiler warning but my linting tool will give me a violation for a non-zero initialization.

Comment: "an enum is an unsigned int at the end of the day" - an `enum` is a plain `int`, not an `unsigned int`.

Comment: Why are you using `0u` rather than `0`?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: An enumeration constant is of type `int`. A enumeration *type* is compatible with some implementation-defined integer type, which may be either signed or unsigned as long as it can hold all the specified values.

Comment: I misspoke about the unsigned. Anyway, I used the 0u instead of the 0 out of habit, there was no reason for it to have the u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really, *literally* want to initialize all the memory of a struct to 0, then that's spelled

```
memset(&bar, 0, sizeof(bar_t));
```

That's actually fairly common, and it even tends to work, but technically it's incorrect for what most people actually want.  It is not guaranteed to do the right thing for most element types, because C makes fewer guarantees than many people think about the representations of values of different types, and about the meaning of various bit patterns.

The correct way to initialize an aggregate object (such as a struct) as if assigning the value zero to every element is what you started with, though the canonical way to write it is simply

```
bar_t bar = { 0 };
```

(no need for the 'u' suffix).  There is a remote possibility that that variant would avoid the compiler warning, though I wouldn't really expect so.

Ashalynd gives the answer I think is most correct (that is,

```
bar_t bar = { foo1 };
```

).  If that somehow violates code conventions with which you must comply, then perhaps you could reorganize your `struct` so that the first element is of any type other than an `enum` type.

Comment: reorganizing the struct so that a non-enumerated type is first does the trick. Now bar_t bar = { 0 }; will work without any warnings or MISRA violations. But why should it matter whether an enum is first or not?

Comment: I do not want to "literally" initialize this memory to 0 :). I'd much rather do it the canonical way. In this case am actually going to use this for static memory, but this question still applied with dynamic or statck). But if I initialize static memory using = { 0 } my linker will know to automatically place this structure in a segment that is entirely initialized to 0. It keeps my memory map cleaner and easier to follow if all of my zeroed out memory is grouped in the same segment and also saves some cycles at boot.

Comment: It matters (to your compiler) because the `0` in `= { 0 }` explicitly initializes the *first* scalar member (defined recursively for sub-structs, sub-unions, and sub-arrays), leaving the rest to be implicitly initialized to `0`. `= { 0 }` is a common and useful idiom, and a good C compiler *shouldn't* complain about it.

Comment: What @Kieth said.  And that's also undoubtedly why the compiler complains when your `enum` is first -- it would (should) issue exactly the same warning if you wrote `foo_t f = 0u` -- and why I said Ashalynd's `bar_t bar = { foo1 }` is more correct.  Many compilers do warn about assigning `int`s to `enum`s, because of the possibility that the value assigned does not correspond to any of the declared enum constants.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! I'll file that away to try to make sure a scalar member ends up at the first location in my arrays a unions.