# warning enumerated type mixed with another type?

Tags: c, enums, compiler-warnings

I have a function accepting 3 unsigned int args `func(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)`. While calling it i am passing enum which is initialized to "2" as 1st argument. getting this warning `Warning[Pe188]: enumerated type mixed with another type` . how to rectify it?

Comment: Posting a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would make this question a lot easier to answer.

Comment: Please provide code...

Comment: Are you sure you aren't using C++ compiler?

Comment: @alk i am using c compiler

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27137998/694576

Answer (score 2):

The question doesn't tell what exactly you are trying to pass, but it looks like the function expects an enum type for the the parameter where as it's supplied an integer. Remember `enum`s are `int`s are different types.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using a C compiler and you cannot change the definition of the function that should be called to take the enum-type in question as parameters:

1. Make sure all enum values you are using in this context are `>=0`.
2. Cast the variables passed in to `unsigned int` to silence the compiler.
3. Add a commment explaining what the cast is about.

This is not nice.

Answer (score -1):

enum and int types are different;
in your case-> Convert the Enum to int by casting :

```
   public enum EmloyeeRole
    {
 None = 0,
 Manager = 1,
 Admin = 2,
 Operator = 3
     }

   EmloyeeRole role = EmloyeeRole.Manager;
       int roleInterger = (int)role;
```

and then you can pass the new int ( roleInteger ) to the function func(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int).

Good luck :)

Comment: @Hassan : i tried your approach, still getting warning :(

Comment: public? The question is tagged with C.